# Importing once exported .py file back to IPython Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I use Ipython Notebook for all python scripting and also making notes with markdown cells.

Sometime back I had downloaded my Ipython Notebook as *xyz.py* file using File>Download Notebook as .py file option.

Now I need to import the same *xyz.py* file back into Ipython Notebook.

How can I achieve this?

Have tried creating a new Notebook and in a cell ran

**%load xyz.py**

but it loads the raw contents of the file in a single cell.
And does not render markdown cells and code cells content as it was there in the original Notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand the Python .py file export is one direction process as it loses information in the process.

If you wish to repopen the notebooks for edit [use the native JSON (ipynb) format](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html#notebook-json-file-format).

For now your option is to reconstruct the cells from the source code by hand.